# Ubuntu ld can not find lRcpp

Tags: ubuntu, ld, rcpp

I installed Rcpp through `r-cran-rcpp` and I use `dpkg -L r-cran-rcpp` to find out that

```
ls /usr/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/libs/
Rcpp.so
```

But when I use `ld -L /usr/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/libs -l Rcpp` ld complaines that it could not find Rcpp, any idea what happened?

In fact, I am working with a first example by Seamless R and C++
Integration with Rcpp,but this following code complain can't find lrcpp

first the cpp code in fib.cpp

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
int fibonacci(const int x) {

if (x == 0) return(0);

 if (x == 1) return(1);

return (fibonacci(x - 1)) + fibonacci(x - 2);

 }

extern "C" SEXP fibWrapper(SEXP xs) {

int x = Rcpp::as<int>(xs);

 int fib = fibonacci(x);

return (Rcpp::wrap(fib));

 }
```

~                       then I try to compile them

```
 PKG_CXXFLAGS="-I/home/sunxd/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/Rcpp/include" \
 PKG_LIBS="-L/home/sunxd/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/Rcpp/libs -lRcpp" \
R CMD SHLIB fib.cpp
```

or

```
PKG_CXXFLAGS="-I/usr/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include" \
 PKG_LIBS="-L/usr/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/libs -lRcpp" \
R CMD SHLIB fib.cpp
```

Comment: Please please _please_ **please** at least try to read some of the documentation and existing examples. I _literally_ wrote a book about it, have a website full of presentation and answered _hundreds_ of questions here.  And in very brief: your assumptions are wrong.

Comment: Hi, Dirk, actually I am reading your book and trying to work out the fibnacci.cpp example, but it compain can't find rcpp, see updates

Comment: The examples in the work all work.  From your (somewhat incomplete) two questions I am guestimating you are trying to compile an executable.  Rcpp is a for extensions called from R.

Comment: And by turning `verbose` on you you can _study_ each of the working builds and see what they do differently.

Comment: Ok, the update helps. Now we can at least try to read what you tried.

Comment: I have added more detailed information, thanks :)

Comment: And in the meantime I wrote you a detailed answer.  `PKG_LIBS` is simply outdated.  You don't need it, as we no longer have a linkable Rcpp library.

Comment: And we both re-learned that _complete_ and _reproducible_ questions make it easier for both sides.  So next time please don't just drop three lines as a question as nobody will know what you had done leading up to it.

Comment: Hi, you're right, I learned from this and had another question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40553356/modify-a-makefile-with-rcpp, maybe this is due to I haven't read carefully about your book, but has to sleep now and have a look again tomorrow. Thanks for your help:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, now that we have a complete question with something reproducible, we can address this:

1. OP tries to reproduce an intro example from my 2013 book
2. When the book came out, we still *linked* against Rcpp.
3. Not longer after, that changed and we now use something which combines *only headers* plus instantiating at load time (instead of linking)
4. With that the linking step is redundant.
5. If you update the example to have empty (or unset) `PKG_LIBS` then all is good:

Complete example:

```
/tmp$ cat fibonacci.cpp 

#include <Rcpp.h>

int fibonacci(const int x) {
   if (x == 0) return(0);
   if (x == 1) return(1);
   return (fibonacci(x - 1)) + fibonacci(x - 2);
}

extern "C" SEXP fibWrapper(SEXP xs) {
   int x = Rcpp::as<int>(xs);
   int fib = fibonacci(x);
   return (Rcpp::wrap(fib));
}
/tmp$ cat rcpp.sh
#!/bin/sh
PKG_CXXFLAGS="-I/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include" \
PKG_LIBS="" \
R CMD SHLIB fibonacci.cpp
/tmp$ ./rcpp.sh 
g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG     -I/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include -fpic  -g -O3 -Wall -pipe -Wno-unused -pedantic -c fibonacci.cpp -o fibonacci.o
g++ -shared -L/usr/lib/R/lib -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -o fibonacci.so fibonacci.o -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR
/tmp$
```

You can now load `fibonacci.so`.

These days, Rcpp Attributes is *much* better. See its vignette.